# Trying to save pyspark dataframe with double quotes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a pyspark dataframe that looks like this

```
"col1"      "col2"      "col3"

"value1"    "value2"    value3

"value4"    "value5"    value6
```

Want to save it as csv file. so I tried the following option

```
df.write.format('csv').option('delimitor',',').option("quote",'').save(path)
```

it is working fine for the data element, but for headers it is not working.

the output looks like this

```
"""col1""","""col2""","""col3"""

"value1","value2",value3

"value4","value5",value6
```

The output should be look like this

```
"col1","col2","col3"

"value1","value2",value3

"value4","value5",value6
```

In the header part extra double quotes are added. The data part looks fine.

Any suggestion what am I missing here. Tried quoteAll but didn't worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code, it should be `option('delimiter`), *not* `delimitor`. Also you can make it easier on yourself by using the `header` option:

```
df.write.format('csv').option('delimiter', ',').option('quote', '').option('header', 'true').save(path)
```

When `header` is set to 'true', the first row of the output file will contain the column names. When set to 'false', the column names will not be included in the output file.